# How to upload files on Windows with '.pem' extension

Tags: javascript, file, encryption, pem

I have an application which is making a file with publicKey with encrypt.js. User can download this file as "PublicKey.pem" as certificate. In the same app user can upload this file, and app will encrypt key and make it as string. And all of this is working fine on Mac and Linux. But when I am trying to upload the same file on Windows, the file has no "type" and can't be read with Reader. What is different on Windows in uploading file with .pem extension and what can I do to fix it?

My code to download file:

```
    let element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 
      encodeURIComponent(data));
    element.setAttribute('download', "PublicKey.pem");
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
```

My code to upload file:

```
    const file = event.target.files[0]
    let reader = new FileReader()
    const textFile = "application/x-x509-ca-cert";
    if (file.type.match(textFile)) {
       reader.onload = function (event) {
       self.setState({ privateFile: event.target.result });
      }
     }
    reader.readAsText(file);
```

My expectation is to read file 'PublicKey.pem', but now I am getting file with no type and which on Windows cannot read FileReader().

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It is couse of in Linux and Mac system get type of file from it's name. On Windows we should write it on our own.